# Shared variable values changing every time when report is refreshing

Tags: crystal-reports

I had an issue with shared variables in Crystal Reports. I used following shared variables in formula

```
Shared NumberVar CC31To50;   
Shared NumberVar CC0To30;   
Shared NumberVar CC61To80;  
Shared NumberVar CC51To60;  
Shared NumberVar CCUnk;  
If {Command.cst_rf_label} = '0-30% of area median income (extremely low)' Then
    CC0To30:=CC0To30+1  
Else If{Command.cst_rf_label} <> '0-30% of area median income (extremely low)' Then
    CC31To50:=CC31To50+1  
Else If{Command.cst_rf_label} <> '0-30% of area median income (extremely low)' Then 
    CC51To60:=CC51To60+1   
Else If{Command.cst_rf_label} <> '0-30% of area median income (extremely low)' Then
    CC61To80:=CC61To80+1  
Else If ISNULL({Command.cst_rf_label}) Then
    CCUnk:=CCUnk+1
```

The issue is every time when I'm refreshing report, the values from these shared variables are changing. Can any one please suggest whats going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what data is retrived from database

Comment: Your all *else if* statements are same i.e. `Else If{Command.cst_rf_label} <> '0-30% of area median income (extremely low)' Then`. Is it so or a typo?

Comment: there is a parameter called domain. It was working fine for all domain values except one...

Comment: Hi Haraman, Sorry I typed it wrong they supposed to be different values.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your report (in the report header) you should initialize all your shared variables in a formula field. Set them all to 0. Then when you refresh your report you will  always get the same results.

Create a formula field like so:

```
Shared NumberVar CC31To50:=0;   
Shared NumberVar CC0To30:=0;   
Shared NumberVar CC61To80:=0;  
Shared NumberVar CC51To60:=0;  
Shared NumberVar CCUnk:=0;

0
```

Place this formula field in the report header. You can format that field using suppress zero.